# Something went wrong with my arrays and integers in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm really sorry because I didn't put the code in English and because I didn't write the all of code, that you can understand it then.

So I edited and deleted the post I've written and here Is all the code with some comments to help you understand it. Problem is marked with *** , and if I know that this is probably very stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer.

HERE IT IS: `// Creates the array with automaticlly generated values to 100
            int arrayNumber = 0;
            List array = new List();

```
        while(true){
            if (array.Count == 100){

                break;
            } else{
            array.Add(arrayNumber);
                arrayNumber++;

            } 
        }



        // Changes the title of program
        Console.Title = "Calculator of time spent in school.";

        // Prints welcome message
        Console.WriteLine("Hi user.!");

        // Sleeps for a while
        Thread.Sleep(1500);

        // Writes the next message
        Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to Calculator of time spent in school.");

        Thread.Sleep(2500);

    DoAgain:

        Console.Clear();

        // Asks user when school starts in hours
        Console.Write("Write the time when school starts in hours: ");

        Thread.Sleep(500);

        // Creates new variable type of INT and checks is it valid
        string TIMEschoolStarts = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        int timeSchoolStarts;

        if (Convert.ToInt32(TIMEschoolStarts) < 6)
        {
            timeSchoolStarts = Convert.ToInt32(TIMEschoolStarts);
            do
            {
                timeSchoolStarts++;

            } while (timeSchoolStarts < 6);

        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(TIMEschoolStarts) > 18)
        {
            timeSchoolStarts = Convert.ToInt32(TIMEschoolStarts);
            do
            {
                timeSchoolStarts--;

            } while (timeSchoolStarts > 18);

        }
        else if (array.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(TIMEschoolStarts)) == false)
        {
            goto DoAgain;
        }

        // Creates new variable for the Time in Minutes when school starts
        Console.Write("Write the time when school starts in minutes: ");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string TimesInMinutes = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        int minutesTime;

        // Checks is variable written and edit it
        if (TimesInMinutes == "")
        {
            minutesTime = 0;

        }
        else {
            minutesTime = Convert.ToInt32(TimesInMinutes);
        }

        Console.Clear();

        Console.Write("Write how much classes you have: ");
        int numberOfClasses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Clear();

        int timeSpentHours, timeSpentMinutes, timeSpent;

        // Gives new values of time SPENT in school
        timeSpent = numberOfClasses * 45 + (numberOfClasses - 2) * 5 + 20;
        timeSpentHours = timeSpent / 60;
        timeSpentMinutes=timeSpent % 60;

        // Gives new values of time to the variables
        // ****            
        timeSchoolStarts += timeSpentHours;
        // ****
        minutesTime += timeSpentMinutes;

        // Prints the value when school is ending to the user
        Console.WriteLine("School is ending in {0} hours, {1} minutes.\nTotal time spent in school is {2} hours, {3} minutes.", timeSchoolStarts, minutesTime, timeSpentHours, timeSpentMinutes);

        Thread.Sleep(4000);

        Console.Write("\Type RUN to start program again: ");
        string again = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        if (again.ToUpper()=="RUN") {
            goto DoAgain;`
```

PS : Just to know this is program what calculates time spent in school. If you find better way to create it please post.

Greetings from Serbia!

Comment: Please provide the actual error message, and indicate which line of code causes the error.

Comment: There are no arrays in code you've posted... Not sure if code actually related to the post - please check.

Comment: There are a few odd solutions in your code, but before we address those, you need to elaborate on what the problem is. `vremeCas += trajanjeCas` is nowhere in the code. Also, it would be very helpful if you could translate the variable names to English, as most of us have no idea what `trajanjeCas` means.

Comment: I don't see arrays anywhere, LOL. I do see a bunch of attempts at conversions without exception handling, maybe the question is phrased wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At first: the return value of ReadLine() is a string, the convert is unnecessary.

Second: The do-while loop is also unnecessary.

Third: goto is a no go in a clean code!

Fourth: Is "niz" the array and whats your target ?